# MOSS Alternate Access Mappings

Tags: sharepoint, moss, dns

I have created a new MOSS site on the following port listed in the Alternate Access Mappings as:

http://sharepoint:27478      Default       http://sharepoint:27478

I now want to configure a domain name to point at this. I have the domain configured to look at http://sharepoint, which is the name of the server.

What would I need to change in the Alternate Access Mappings?

All the best

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Central Administration >> Operations >> Global Configuration >>Alternative Access Mappings`
Here just select your existing application http://sharepoint:27478, then put the new url (with domain name) in the required zone.

This Technet article on [Configure alternate access mapping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx) should help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add is the external name.

Which would look like:

http://sharepoint:27478 Default http://www.mywebsite.com

Also read this series of blog posts:

> [What every SharePoint administrator needs to know about Alternate Access Mappings (Part 1 of 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx)

Comment: The link above seems to not work?

Comment: There's the updated link. It might be a problem with stack encoding.

Comment: (Although they both work for me now.)